# Array length in angularjs returning zero even though the data is present

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

JS:

```
    $scope.find = function() {
        $scope.onlyUsers = Users.query();
        console.log(" $scope.onlyUsers-->", $scope.onlyUsers);
        var len = $scope.onlyUsers.length;
        console.log('length',+len); 
        var peruser = [{}];
        if(data){
          for(var x=0; x< $scope.onlyUsers.length; x++){
            if( $scope.onlyUsers[x].orgId == $scope.authentication.user.orgId)
            peruser.push(data[x]);
            }
            }
            console.log('peruser--->',peruser);
          }
        }
    };
```

But in console $scope.onlyUsers data is coming .
console:

`$scope.onlyUsers--> []
0 Resource { __v=0, _id="547dc4a4ae31830800267e48", displayName="praveen Nune", more...}

1 Resource { __v=0, _id="547daf3bae31830800267e47", displayName="siva google12344545", more...} 
2 Resource { __v=0, _id="547dae6eaf1a68c01c8020cc", displayName="siva acertis564e54354", more...}

3 Resource { __v=0, _id="547dabf151fc25a40124a9ff", displayName="microsoft google453234", more...}

4 Resource { __v=0, _id="547dab68571f9d0800bef142", displayName="e43545345 rtrgtr453", more...} 
5 Resource { __v=0, _id="547da711078519dc14590cc4", displayName="microsoft acertis564e5", more...}

6 Resource { __v=0, _id="547da009a5a2493007f6a3de", displayName="microsoft acertis6786", more...}
7 Resource { salt=""?5???~?_?|?]?c", provider="local", role="54756bbc089822ac1fcd0226", more...}

8 Resource { __v=0, _id="547d983093b8cb181307751f", displayName="sap google56987", more...}
9 Resource { __v=0, _id="547d9605e9847d601062ea3f", displayName="mico admin", more...}
10 Resource { __v=0, _id="547d950ddbcdb90800a495d0", displayName="google user5678", more...}`

and length is coming as zero. How to get the length?...plz help me

```
length 0
```

Comment: Not all Arrays are true JS arrays. If it's not keeping track of it's length property, why not just do a loop through and calculate the length... Or do a loop through and build an actual array. ALSO - why are you passing the salt to the front-end? That's part of the security that stops dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a callback function to execute when the query method gets data back from the server.

```
$scope.find = function () {
    $scope.onlyUsers = Users.query(function (result) {
        console.log(" $scope.onlyUsers-->", result);
        var len = result.length;
        console.log('length', +len);
        var peruser = [{}];
        if (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                if (result[x].orgId == $scope.authentication.user.orgId)
                    peruser.push(data[x]);
            }
        }
        console.log('peruser--->', peruser)
    });

};
```

See [AngularJS docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

This is the asynchronous data loading issue. Need to use callback or defer methods to solve this issue. The console result is actually populates only after the data fetch complete, but you tried to get the length of the array before the data load completed.